# cakePHP Paginator::numbers() function does not include a page:1 parameter in the link for the first page

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I have been trying to create a component like the Bakery's [Paginator Recall](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mattc/2008/02/04/pagination-recall) that would allow me to save pagination data for CakePHP 2.4 and run into the following issue.

All solutions involve saving the Paginator parameters in the session and then retrieving and applying them upon returning to that same page without specifying any.

This approach would have worked if only the Paginator helper functions like numbers(), first() and previous() would include the page:1 named parameter in the links that they generate for moving to the first page like the corresponding function of the 1.3 version.

Unfortunately all of these functions create URLs without the page parameter when they refer to the first page, so when users click on the first page link, the component does not find any paging info and hence it returns them to the previous position.

There must be some way to work around this, but for the moment I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 2):

NOT including the page number in the link to the first page is by design.

Read the reason on the [CakePHP 2.4 Migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-4-migration-guide.html#paginatorhelper).

I would suggest to use the same convention. When you do not have pagination information assume is page one, and do not add it to your URLs.

So all you have to do is code this special case when then pagination is missing. And in this special case your "recall" component will simply not add that page.

Comment: Fair enough, the thing is that when you land on a page and find paging information in the session you do not really know if you arrived there coming from an other page, in which case you must restore paging data from the session of, if you just wanted to see the first page in  which case you need to manually set page to 1.

Comment: I'd say you can do it like this: IF there is pagination data in the session then your restore it and use it. IF there is no pagination data in the session then this is page 1 and you do not have to do anything. So you only need to be careful of two tings: 1) do not add pagination data to session for page 1 and 2) once you have used the pagination data form the session you need to clear that data (otherwise you will never be able to return to page 1)

Comment: Thanks, that is an other way to think of it, I will try to implement my component like this and see what come out....

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have managed to create a working solution. Thanks to the advice I have received I have now created a working component like the original `PaginationRecallCompoent`.

I have written all the details in the following blog [post](http://abakalidis.blogspot.gr/2014/01/cakephp-saving-paging-data-in-session.html).